# Microsoft bot framework carousel with multiple buttons

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I want to make a carousel as in the image below for facebook messenger using Microsoft bot framework

[image]

```
export function SuboffertCard(subOffert: SubOffertCard, session?: builder.Session) {
return new builder.HeroCard(session)
    .title(subOffert.title)
    .subtitle(subOffert.subtitle)
    .images([
        builder.CardImage.create(session, subOffert.image)
            .tap(builder.CardAction.showImage(session, subOffert.image)),
    ])
    .buttons([
        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, `select:get_${subOffert.title}`, polyglot.t("select")),
        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, `select:info_${subOffert.title}`, polyglot.t("info"))
    ])}
```

In the app.ts:

```
 let msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
            .attachments(subOfferts.map(subOffert => SuboffertCard(subOffert, session)));
         builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, subOfferts.map(subOffert => `select:get_${subOffert.title} | select:info_${subOffert.title}` ));
```

But no matter which button I click I receive the same payload .